# Issue when trying to prevent access to an angular application except the login page, using express-jwt

Tags: express, express-jwt

I have an angular + express app. I want to prevent access to the angular application, unless the user is authenticated. To do so, I use jwt to check if the user can access the content, unless the page is the login page in which case it is fine to let anyone access it.

It works fine on the "prevent access" side: if I try to access with no tokens, I get a message saying that the token is not valid. If I try to access with a token, I get to see the angular application.

Where it does not work is on the "unless" part: if I try to access `/dist/login`, I get a blank page. The reason being that the server sends the following files (which are the the files of my angular application):

- `index.html`
- `main.738685558cc44b584d9e.bundle.js`
- other .js files...
- `styles.8ebd0fc21ad0f11c194c.bundle.css`

but while `index.html` has the right content, the other files all have the same wrong content, which is an error: `invalid token...`. The angular application cannot load since the .js files are not correct and I cannot access my login page, thus preventing anyone from accessing the angular application (unless manually setting the token).

How comes the server returns the correct `index.html` but changes the content of the .js files? What would be the proper way to achieve what I want, i.e to prevent access to all the part of my angular application except to the login page? It is easily done in client-side, but I want to have a server-side protection too since the client-side is easily bypassable.

Here is the server code. In reality there is a bit more going on than that (e.g an API providing a token), but it is not important there.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const ejwt = require('express-jwt');

const static = express.static(__dirname + '/dist');

app.use('/dist', ejwt({ secret: 'not so secret' }).unless({ path: ['/dist/auth'] }), static);

// if 404 error, send index.html and let angular handle it
app.use('/app', function (req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/dist/index.html');
});

app.use('/app', function (err, req, res, next) {
  if (err.name === 'UnauthorizedError') {
     res.send('invalid token...');
  }
});

app.use('/', function (req, res, next) {
  res.redirect('/app/');
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server is running'));
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You're very nearly there, your concepts of JWT seem correct and the idea of using middleware to block access to particular authenticated pages. The problem you're having seems to be with serving up your Angular application.

To serve up the angular application you probably don't want to be using `res.sendFile`. Instead, you probably want to have a built version of the angular app (the dist folder from `ng build`) in a folder within your server code. Then you want to use Express's static function. This is built for serving up static content, in this case that is your frontend code.

You'll probably want to do something like:

```
// Assume the frontend project is in the {currentDir}/frontend and the build is then in /dist.
app.use('/app', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/frontend/dist')));
```

This will let Express manage serving up all of your frontend by going to `localhost:3000/app` (assuming you're on port 3000).

Then, all of your other endpoints will be JSON API endpoints, this means they'll return some sort HTTP status code, and JSON as a response. Your angular app can then handle everything the user does on the frontend and just make calls up to the API.

If someone tries to go to `localhost:3000/app/secret-page`, angular will make a HTTP GET call up to your API asking for the secret information. If no JWT has been provided then the server will say "nope" and will return something like

```
HTTP Status Code: 404
Body: { message: "Nothing to see here" }
```

This way your frontend gets served up as soon as the user goes to localhost:3000/app, and then the rest of the calls are all handled by your express code, dealing simply with JSON responses (no HTML files).

This is a very basic example, there are things you may wish to improve about this such as serving up the angular app on the `/` route rather than `/app` but those seem outside of the scope of this question and there are many resources out there to help with this.